# Can't see like plugin iframe on (at least) some browsers

Tags: facebook, iframe

Not sure why. I grabbed the code from:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

And as stated there, we can read:

> "href - the URL to like. The XFBML version defaults to the current
>   page. Note: After July 2013 migration, href should be an absolute URL"

So I did.

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fprojectokairos&amp;width=100&amp;height=21&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
</body>
```

Could this be related with the fact that the page is unpublished?
I hope not because I do need to place the button here and there on several pages before the FB page goes live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being unpublished is possible, but I would also check your plugins. Firefox and Chrome especially. Do you have AdBlockPlus, DoNotTrackMe, or NoScript installed? The last two, I know interfere with the Facebook like button.

Comment: in the rush to check it out, I actually did publish the page and the like button was there. It was there at the very beginning, then it was not there anymore, and all that due to, perhpas, lag time on fb side, perfectible acceptable.